Discord interactions endpoint validation error. Using AWS Lambda with Python 3.12 and Docker
I'm trying to use AWS lambda to host my discord bot, but discord is rejecting the url generated from AWS as an Interactions Endpoint URL
I am using a docker container, and I'm trying out a decorator from discord_interactions.
I have tested my code without the verify_key_decorator, and edited the response json. It was able to return me the DISCORD_PUBLIC_KEY, and the correct message structure. Hence, I believe that AWS lambda is working as intended.
From that, I don't think that the DISCORD_PUBLIC_KEY or the response is the error.
I have also tried adding /interactions to the end of my url, but that did not work too.
I have also tried building with docker on my local machine and opening the port with ngrok, which works.
I did get a ValueError: WSGI wrapper received a non-HTTP scope in my CloudWatch, but I'm not sure what that means, or that it affects anything.
This stackoverflow question did state that it doesn't affect anything, but it is for a different module (hypercorn instead of flask)
This means that my code is correct, and the 3 potential failpoints are my Dockerfile, lambda-stack file, or the Mangum and WsgiToAsgi packages.
Here is stack (config) file from the lib folder
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import * as lambda from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";

export class DiscordBotLambdaStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const dockerFunction = new lambda.DockerImageFunction(
      this,
      "DockerFunction",
      {
        code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset("./src"),
        memorySize: 1024,
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(10),
        architecture: lambda.Architecture.X86_64,
        
      }
    );

    const functionUrl = dockerFunction.addFunctionUrl({
      authType: lambda.FunctionUrlAuthType.NONE,
      cors: {
        allowedOrigins: ["*"],
        allowedMethods: [lambda.HttpMethod.ALL],
        allowedHeaders: ["*"],
      },
    });

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "FunctionURLValue",{value:functionUrl.url} );
  }
}


And here is the Dockerfile I used for AWS lambda
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12

# Copy requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install the specified packages
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV DISCORD_PUBLIC_KEY="ed1dbc1440da**************************************409b10693c8ec7"
# Copy all files in ./app
COPY src/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "main.handler" ]



Here is the Dockerfile I used when building locally. Do note that this runs like a server, while AWS lambda runs serverless
# Use an official Python runtime as a base image
FROM python:3.12-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# I don't think this is needed but it doesn't break anything
COPY app/* /app

# Expose the port the app will run on
EXPOSE 5000

# Define environment variable for Flask
ENV FLASK_APP=main.py

# Command to run the Flask app
CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]

Here is the code in my main.py file
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from mangum import Mangum
from asgiref.wsgi import WsgiToAsgi
from discord_interactions import verify_key_decorator


app = Flask(__name__)
asgi_app = WsgiToAsgi(app)
handler = Mangum(asgi_app)

DISCORD_PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get("DISCORD_PUBLIC_KEY")

@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
async def interactions():
    raw_request = request.json
    return interact(raw_request)


@verify_key_decorator(DISCORD_PUBLIC_KEY)
def interact(raw_request):
    if raw_request["type"] == 1:  # PING
        response_data = {"type": 1}  # PONG

    return jsonify(response_data)

I have also seen Unable to verify Discord signature for bot on AWS Lambda Python 3 (Interactions_Endpoint_URL), but I don't think I need an API key for my application.
From what I know, a request will be sent to a link like https://mghi6fpwhzphw6xfbm3zzwnvtq0nnvsl.lambda-url.ap-southeast-1.on.aws, which will cause the AWS lambda bot to wake up.
What should I do to get rid of the validation error?
